# Proof of Ratio Test in divergence case

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to prove ratio test for divergence case

> if $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| \geq 1$ for $n\geq n_{0}$, where $n_{0}$ is some fixed integer, then series $\sum a_{n}$ diverges

All books I found explained it just $a_{n}$ cannot be $0$, so series diverges.

It seems, of course, obvious but how can I prove that $|a_{n+1}|\ge |a_{n}|$ and $a_n\neq 0$ implies $\lim a_{n}$ cannot be $0$?

My proof:

For fixed $N$, we can choose $M$ such that $n\geq M \implies |a_{n}| \leq |a_{N}|$
(Here $|a_{N}|$ plays role of $\epsilon$)
But it gives contradiction for sufficiently large $n$, specifically $n > N, M$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should state that you are using proof by contradiction. So, suppose $\sum a_n$ converges. Then it is necessary that $a_n\to 0$.

Setting $\epsilon = |a_N|$, you have $|a_n|< |a_N|$ for all $n$ larger than some $M$. But, if you pick $n>\max (N,M)$, you contradict the assumption $$|a_n/a_N|=|a_n/a_{n-1}|\dots |a_{N+1}/a_N|\ge 1\cdot 1\dots 1$$

Comment: Thanks. I have mistake in my post. how about $|a_{n+1}| \geq |a_{n}|$? not strict inequality. of course $a_{n}$ is nonzero for well-defined of fraction.

Comment: I edited my response